# ms-sql запрос с N-ой строки

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть ли в MS-SQL способ вывода запроса с N-ой строки?
Например, что бы запрос выдал все из таблицы за исключением первых двух строк.

Comment: А сервер какой ? с 2012 есть OFFSET. До этого нумеровать записи row_number() и отбирать по условию

Comment: Сервер использую 2008. row_number() как раз таки и использую. Но, чует мое сердце, что есть более прямой способ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для этого можно использовать `ORDER BY ... OFFSET ...` (доступно с SqlServer 2012 и далее):

```
select A, B, C
from TableName
order by ColumnName
offset 2 rows
```

В SqlServer 2008 для этих целей можно воспользоваться функцией `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
;with t as (
    select A, B, C,
        row_num = row_number() over (order by ColumnName)
    from TableName
)
select A, B, C
from t
where row_num > 2
order by row_num;
```

Comment: offset не работает в mssql 2008.